# Procedurally Generated Texture Scaling based on Surface Curve

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders

I've got a fairly simple character that I'm texturing procedurally, and my question is this:

Is there a way to tell the Voronoi texture base that I'm using to have variable scale based on how flat/curved the surface its applied to is?  IE, the scales on its belly would be larger than the scales on its arms because the belly has a flatter surface area than the arm tubes.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide visual examples?

Comment: Yup, added to the original post.

Comment: ... and is something preventing you from scaling the UVs of the belly in order to obtain exactly what you want?

Comment: It literally did not occur to me that I could just, y'know, SCALE THE UVs themselves.  I'll give it a shot, but I'm also kinda worried that way would turn out messy.

Comment: Oof, yeah I tried just editing the UVs and there's all sorts of warping problems.  Thanks for the suggestion Bruno, but this ain't it.

Comment: On second pass, I tried using an image texture with grayscale values of where I wanted large scales vs small scales and tried cramming that into the Scale node, but the warping was SO much worse with that than Bruno's method.  Revisiting editing the UV map with various falloffs wound up working the best, so I'm gonna stick with that.

Comment: Just a little alarm-bell going off for me.. if this character deforms, you _might_ not want the scales' sizes to change when it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a grayscale image to set the factor of the scale of... heh, the scales. That's an incredibly esoteric thing to say, so here is my setup (please forgive my liberal use of "reroute" nodes, I wanted to fit it all in at a decent resolution);

[image]

Which results in this (with the "factor" texture that's used in the above node setup, but you can paint the values however you want);

[image]

I'm also including the .blend file;

[image]